# Importing webpack bundle throws module.default is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I've built a package A and trying to load and use from B.
A is being transpiled with Babel and then bundled with webpack.

A index.js:

```js
function A_moduleFunction() { // A logic }
export default A_moduleFunction
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'transpile/index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index.js'
    }
}
```

On package B, I'm trying to import A and call `A_moduleFunction`:

```js
import a_moduleFunction from 'A' // A is defined in package.json
a_moduleFunction()
```

But Then an error is thrown:

```
TypeError: (0 , _a_moduleFunction.default) is not a function
```

I used same definitions for webpack and Babel from another project of mine, which uses requires instead of imports..
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is your Webpack config for `A` or `B`? If `A`, why are you pre-bundling a library?